# string manipulation "^" shows end of message in string

Tags: c#, .net

**C# Code...**

```
     string[] array = new string[] { "12", "34", "5^67", "8^945", "^63^", "9484^" };
                    foreach(string message in array)
                    {
                              FindString(message)

                    }
 string remainingString = "";
        string tempString = "";
private void FindString(string message)
        {

            if(message.Contains("^"))
            {//remove char ^ process
                int pos = -1;
                pos = message.IndexOf('^');
                outputString = message.Substring(0, pos);
                remainingString = message.Substring(pos);
                if(tempString != "")
                {
                    outputString = tempString + outputString;
                    tempString = "";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                tempString = tempString + message;
            }

        }
```

**From array i have to get messages 12345,678,945,63,9484.
“^” shows end of message in string**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you told us what the error is you are experiencing we might be able to help.

Comment: are you trying to split the string??

Comment: yes like split dont want to use split.message will be pass to function like above 6 cases using that 6 cases i have find out messages "^" shows end of message.

Comment: Why can't you use split? Don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Why am I smelling homework???

Comment: And he votes down 2 perfectly valid answers.

Comment: see i have edit quetion Now u better understand

Comment: @Nikhil where is the question??? Its just some code...

Comment: From array i have to get messages 12345,678,945,63,9484. “^” shows end of message in string

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] array = new string[] { "12", "34", "5^67", "8^945", "^63^", "9484^" };
                foreach(string message in array)
                {
                          FindString(message)

                }
 string remainingString = "";
 string tempString = "";
 private void FindString(string message)
    {

        while(message.Contains("^"))
        {//remove char ^ process
            int pos = -1;
            pos = message.IndexOf('^');
            outputString = message.Substring(0, pos);
            message = message.Substring(pos + 1); // <--- LOOK HERE
            if(tempString != "")
            {
                outputString = tempString + outputString;
                tempString = "";
            }

        }

        tempString = tempString + message;


    }
```

Of course the better option yet is to `string.Join` the array, then `.Split` on the result:

```
string[] answers = string.Join("", messages).Split("^").ToArray();
```

Comment: see i have edit quetion Now u better understand

Comment: Rob u see my updated  quetion

Comment: Ah yes, you finally put a question in there, though it isn't phrased as a question. I added an answer that answers that too. Just add the if statement to findstring on the remaining string if it isn't length 0..

Comment: using those if condition it never executes function..

Comment: Rob Please give me proper answer :(..

Comment: Rob using above code only three messages i get "12345","678", "945"  not get "63" "9484"

Comment: R u there Rob.............

Comment: Sorry Nikhil, I was passing out last night from exhaustion. Looked at it this morning and I think I found a way to do it quite easily without recursion - take a look. Changed the if to a while, and changed 'remainingString' to just replace the previous message. Give it a shot.

Comment: chk ur code u have not format closing loop

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting by the input string:

```
var output = string.split('^').ToList();
```

Comment: see i have edit quetion Now u better understand

Comment: So you want to combine your string array into a single string, then break that string into several '^' delimited parts without using split?